# Get records of two separate columns in one column MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MYSQL database that are `sales` and `purchase` in these I have the columns `sale_date` and `purchase_date` respectively.

I want all `sale_date` and `purchase_date` in some temporary column as `all_dates`.
I tried

```
Select 
    sale_date, purchase_date 
from 
    sales, purchase
```

this returns me two columns. Now I want to group these dates in one column but can't figure it out how to get desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```sql
SELECT 
    sale_date AS all_dates
FROM sales

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    purchase_date AS all_dates
FROM purchase
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19270/1)** demo

Comment: just as a side note: If the OP wants all dates I would recommend `UNION ALL` as union will remove duplicates

Comment: No sir, i already had tried this. As union removes duplication that's why I don't need this.

Comment: @user3826986 then use UNION ALL?? did you not read my comment?

Comment: @JohnRuddell thanks for your comment, its working fine one more question that how can i set alias for this?

Comment: `SELECT sale_date AS all_dates FROM sales UNION ALL SELECT purchase_date AS all_dates FROM purchase` something like that